# Segmentation Fault at the end of file

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm getting the following error at the end of my file:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
At X:\Sorted\Coding\C++\Weighted Grade Calculator\Source.cpp:55
```

I don't understand why this is happening, because the line in question only contains a `}`. Take a look:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numberweights;
    int current = 1;
    bool verbose = true;

    float grades[] = {}, weights[] = {};


    cout << "How many weights are there?";
    cin >> numberweights;

    /*-----------------------------------------------------*/

    for(int i = numberweights; i > 0; i--) {
        cout << "What is the weight for weight #" << current << "?";
        cin >> weights[current - 1];

        current++;

        if(verbose) {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "I:" << i << "  " << "current:" << current << endl;
        }
    }
    current--;
    int rep = 0;

    cout << weights[0];
    cout << weights[1];
    return 1;
}
```

Often, `i` randomly jumps to a number above 1 billion. Why is this happening?

Comment: how do you compile? does the problem occur in debug and release mode or ?

Comment: There aren't 55 (or more) lines in your posted code, so it obviously does not align with the error message, which states that the issue occurred at line 55 in the source file. Help us help you and at least indicate which line is the one where the error occurred... That said, UKMonkey identifies at least one possible cause for a SIGSEGV below (item 3). There are quite possibly others, though...

Comment: @twalberg it seems that Stackoverflow might have removed some spacing. If you copy it back into an editor, it is line 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. good formatting is your friend.
2. you don't open / close files, so your question is a little misleading.
3. weights[current - 1] is undefined behaviour, as the size of your array is 0.

Change your arrays to be std::vector, and then perform a resize to make them the size you want.
Since you're writing to memory which hasn't been allocated in defined way, i is probably jumping because you're writing to it when you try to write to your array.  Once you're writing to an array (or vector) that is big enough for the job, your 'i' should behave as expected

Welcome to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Just to add a little bit more - user input shouldn't be trusted.
You're reading an integer from the user, and trusting they've not put in a negative one.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is ill-formed because:

```
float grades[] = {}, weights[] = {};
```

`grades` and `weights` is zero length array.

g++ reports it as an error why clang, incorrectly, makes it a warning (because they're confused it with flexible member array, an extension to C++, taken from C99).